# Would this library be interesting to dApp developers for in-browser wallet?

Tags: wallets, smart-contract-wallets, library, frontend, layer-2

I'm with INTMAX, developing webmax.js, a JS library for quick dApp integration with our in-browser web3 wallet that's secure, uses biometric authentication, & supports EVM-compatible / Layer 2 networks, eliminating user friction by keeping them in the dApp environment. Our new library allows direct connection to biometrics, easy integration, and is versatile and interoperable.

Would any front-end devs here be able to review it (https://github.com/InternetMaximalism/webmax.js) and maybe chat briefly with our founder (who's a respected developer who was a researcher in the origin of zkRollup, and the inventor of the zkRollup preconsensus mechanism, so may be cool for you to meet in any case).

Many thanks.